# Why does Spring Security not work with aws-serverless-web-native-app?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, aws-serverless, graalvm, aws-sam-cli

Trying to add security filters to my spring native application which was gonna deploy on aws lambda. So took a help of sample example of [pet-store-native](https://github.com/aws/serverless-java-container/tree/main/samples/springboot3/pet-store-native)(spring boot + graalvm + aws serverless application). But adding filters to it, not working in an expected way.

Things not working as expected :

1. .authorizeHttpRequests is not authorising request as specified.
2. Some filters are running inside security filter chain and some are running outside it.

Security Configuration.class ->

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .cors(cors -> cors.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                auth
                        .requestMatchers("/pets").authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll();
                // .anyRequest().permitAll();
            })
            .addFilterAfter(outsideFilter, CorsFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(simpleFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .sessionManagement(
                    sm -> sm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).sessionFixation().none());

    return http.build();
}
```

OutsideProjectFilter.class (Using OncePerRequestFilter) ->

```
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
            System.out.println("Running a filter outisde the current project.");

            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

SimpleFilter.class (Using OncePerRequestFilter) ->

```
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Running a simple filter");
    
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

DemoApplication.class ->

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.sample.filters","com.amazonaws.serverless.sample.springboot3"})
public class DemoApplication {
```

Trace Showing filters running outside filter chain ->

[Trace log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK66r.png)

And even specifying .requestMatchers("/pets").authenticated(), able to access this endpoint.

[Making curl request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLmFE.png)

Implementation - [Source code on Github](https://github.com/AniS-03/demo-aws-serverless-web-native-app)

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. Spring Boot will automatically add filters to the filter chain when detected, if you add them as security filters as well they will be executed twice. Register a `FilterRegistrationBean` for each filter to disable the registration in the regular filter chain.

Comment: If they will be executed twice, then "Running a simple filter" shouldn't be printed twice in trace? But it just got print once and that before security filter chain.

Comment: Because you are extending `OncePerRequestFilter`, which, as the name implies, only runs once per request.

Comment: Actually I have already tried adding FilterRegistrationBean, but that hadn't worked. Also I have a doubt like why the same thing not happens twice and filters runs normally like security filter and even without specifying FilterRegistrationBean when I run it like a simple spring boot application?

Comment: Also if spring boot is registering them as normal filter then shouldn't both run before security filter chain?

Comment: That depends on the ordering as well. Again you are using a `OncePerRequestFilter` as the base so they will execute once always BUT not always as part of the security chain. If you only want them as part of the chain you must use a `FilterRegistrationBean` to disable it. Nonetheless the filters aren't your problem The logging shows `/hello` and not `/pets` so not sure what you want to handle. Please show the endpoint.

Comment: Actually logs were same for both /hello and /pets. But I was just trying to show that I was able to make request to /pets endpoint with providing anything for authentication in second image. And for code I will provide GitHub repo link by tomorrow.

Comment: Added the link to GitHub repository, kindly check it by running as native image using sam because it works when running normally as spring boot app. If possible try comparing both and please help me if I am wrong somewhere in implementation.